# Extract hashtags from non ASCII strings using regex

Tags: php, regex

How do i can extract hashtags from a `non-ASCII` string , using regex ?

For example :

`$str = #Hello   #سلام   #hello-again   #سلام_دوباره   #hello_again`

I wouldn't like bad characters like `! @ $ % ^ ♫ ►` that included in hashtag , be accepted.

I tried this but it accepts bad characters :

```
preg_match_all('/#([^\s]+)/', $str, $matches);
```

it accepts `#►☻`

Comment: Did you try anything? Helping means helping you understand what is wrong with your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the following regex:

```
'/#([\w-]+)/u'
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pC0qO3/1). The `/u` modifier will allow handling of Unicode symbols, and `\w` will match Unicode letters.

The regex breakdown:

- `#` - a `#` symbol
- `([\w-]+)` - 1 or more characters that are either letters, numbers,  underscores or hyphens.

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/9i8BgC)

Comment: it works with php. How i can use it with Javascript ?

Comment: No, it won't work with PHP since ES5 does not support the `/u` modifier. You need to use ranges. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rvrn691r/) for a sample.

Comment: @AliN11 Now, except Safari and some other rare browsers, you [can use](https://jsfiddle.net/wiktor_stribizew/k4xs5yce/1/) a similar regex in JavaScript, `const re = /#([\p{L}\p{N}\p{M}\p{Pc}-]+)/gu;`